# form-validate from "less" file is not working when div is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

I have a `.less` file with a `form-validate` class in it. When the input type is set to `url`, and an invalid url is entered, the border turns red.

Normally it works, but when I add the element dynamically, it does not.

The `.less` file is from a template and I don't know much about it.
I'm adding the `input` element dynamically on a button click.

I've added the `form-validate` to the form which is parent.

```
$("#panelHolder").html('<input type="url" name="hostUrl" id="hostUrl" ng-model="hostUrl" placeholder="http://" class="form-control "/>');
```

If the same code is added directly in the `panelHolder`, it works.

```
<form name="myForm" class="form-validate " data-ng-submit="create(myForm.$valid)"
      novalidate>
    <script>
        function showPanel1()
        {
            $("#servicePanelHolder").html('<div id="panel1" class="controls"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Host</label><input type="url" form="syncForm" name="hostUrl" id="hostUrl" ng-model="hostUrl" placeholder="http://"class="form-control "/><span ng-show="form.validateInput(\'url\', \'url\')"></span></div></div>');
        }
        function showPanel2()
        {
            $("#servicePanelHolder").html('<div id="panel2" class="controls"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Access Key</label><input type="text" name="accessKey" id="accessKey" ng-model="accessKey" class="form-control "/></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Secret Access Key</label><input type="text" name="secretKey" id="secretKey" ng-model="secretKey"class="form-control "></div></div>');
        }

    </script>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="name" class="form-control "/>
        </div>

        <legend>Service</legend>

        <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="radio-inline c-radio ">
                <input type="radio" name="type" value="Panel1"
                       checked="" ng-model="type"
                       onchange="showPanel1()"/>
                <span class="fa fa-circle"></span>Panel 1</label>

            <label class="radio-inline c-radio">
                <input type="radio" name="type" value="Panel2"
                       ng-model="type"
                       onchange="showPanel2()"/>
                <span class="fa fa-circle"></span>Panel 2</label>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="panel-body" id="servicePanelHolder">


    </div>

    <div class=" mt">
        <input type="submit" class="mb-sm btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

**UPDATE:** I'm also unable to read values of these elements in my controller when the form is submitted.

Comment: maybe because the check is not being appended to the element? a jsfiddle would be nice to work at for your solution.(ps you forgot a parenthesis at the `.html'<input..` )

Comment: I just realized, i am not able to read values from those elements either!

Comment: @Gomzy, Added. I think its because of something else. I dont get values of these dynamically added elements in my Controller.